# where commands are logged apart from .bash_history?

Tags: command-line, bash, logs

I wish I could restrict access to all files where commands are logged. 
I found these only in .bash_history file located in the home folder.
Is there another place?

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you are referring to; but if logged in locally you can add a ' ' before your command and it won't be recorded in your  .bash_history.  Note: this generally won't apply to remote logins (eg. via ssh), nor if policy was changed to remove this as default (and I'm assuming a desktop install).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you for sharing the ' ' command option. It's great. Well I  researched and it appears that the only place where executed commands are logged are in .bash_history. and the good thing is that the output is not logged in the file. Now with the ' ' addition is even better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, *by default* commands run in `bash` (without any output) are saved in the user’s `~/.bash_history` file only. There are multiple ways to remove lines from this file, e.g.:

- manually remove line(s):

  ```bsh
  # removes line 42
  history -d 42
  # removes lines which just say “exit”
  sed -i '/^exit$/d' ~/.bash_history
  # removes lines containing “/path/” anywhere
  sed -i '\_/path/_d' ~/.bash_history
  ```
- prepend a space to the command you don’t want to be saved  (`␣` means space here):

  ```bsh
  ␣echo secret password | …
  ```

  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984121/507051).
- set the `HISTIGNORE` variable in your `~/.bashrc` to not save certain commands:

  ```bsh
  # ignores lines beginning with “ls ” and lines which just say “clear”
  HISTIGNORE='ls *:clear'
  ```

  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984124/507051).